# How to load ConfigEntity by Field?

Tags: entities

I'm using ConfigEntity and on this Entity, there is a boolean Field (checkbox) called "Published".

Now I want to load all Entities with field Published = 1

Do you know how I can do that?

P.s. To load all Entities I'm using this line below:

```
$myEntities = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('my_entities')->loadMultiple();
```

If there is another best command, please let me know.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$entity_manager = \Drupal::entityTypeManager();
$entity_storage = $entity_manager->getStorage('entity_name_id');
$entitys_published = $entity_storage->loadByProperties([
  'status' => 1, // published
])->loadMultiple();
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried with but it didn't work for me

Comment: @RenatoGonçalves humm, try instead with `'published' => 1,` although I doubt this is correct.

Comment: If not, check both with `=> 0,` maybe there aren't any published?